# gapi.client.request() not working

Tags: javascript, json, google-api, freebase, google-api-client

I am using Google API for freebase and this simple and a perfectly valid call is not working. I've verified from docs that I'm making correct call but chrome debugger says otherwise.

```
var request = gapi.client.request({'path':'freebase/v1/topic/m/0nx5r',
                                   'method':'GET'});
```

Please see the error as seen in JS debugger:
[image]

I know for sure that this method is correct. What's wrong here? [Check here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiclientrequest) is the description of the call.

Answer (score 0):

have you loaded the Google API before ? Like :

```
api.client.setApiKey('API KEY');
gapi.client.load('request', 'v1', callback)
```

i don't know what is before your else statement